# Angular subscribe value is always given the value - 1, the value before the real one

Tags: angular, https, angular6, angular-services, subscribe

I'm trying to execute an event after the `.subscribe` is done beceau the code after it depends of the result

```
verifBordereauExistBase(id: string) {
    return this._BourdereauService.get_one(id).subscribe(
        data = > {
            if (data.idBourdereau == null) {
                this.idBourdereauIsValid = false;
            } else {
                this.idBourdereauIsValid = true;
            }
        }, err = > {
            console.error(err)
        }, () = > {})
}
```

and the main test is here

```
AddBordereautoList() {
  this.verifBordereauExistBase(this.idbordereaux);
  console.log(this.idBourdereauIsValid)
  if (Number.isNaN(Number(this.idbordereaux))) {
      this.notifier.notify('error', 'Format code a bare invalide');
  } else if (this.idbordereaux.length != 10) {
      this.notifier.notify('error', 'Format code a bare invalide');
  } else if (this.idBourdereauIsValid == false) {
      this.notifier.notify('error', 'Bordereau n\'existe pas ');
  } else {
      if (this.map.size == 0) {
          this.map.set(1, this.idbordereaux);
      } else {
          let x: number = this.verifexistbordereau(this.idbordereaux);
          if (x === 0) {
              this.map.set(this.map.size + 1, this.idbordereaux);
          } else {
              this.notifier.notify('error', 'Bordereau N°' + this.idbordereaux + 'existe deja dans la liste!');
          }
      }
  }
  this.idbordereaux = "";
}
```

i'm executing this code and the value of `this.idBourdereauIsValid` is one step behind, it gives me the value - 1 always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code under `this.verifBordereauExistBase(this.idbordereaux);` might be executing before `this.verifBordereauExistBase(this.idbordereaux);` has a chance to return. To ensure it does, add the `AddBordereautoList()` code to the `.subscribe` complete step:

```
verifBordereauExistBase(id: string) {
    return this._BourdereauService.get_one(id).subscribe(
        data = > {
            if (data.idBourdereau == null) {
                this.idBourdereauIsValid = false;
            } else {
                this.idBourdereauIsValid = true;
            }
        }, err = > {
            console.error(err)
        }, () = > {
            console.log(this.idBourdereauIsValid)
            if (Number.isNaN(Number(this.idbordereaux))) {
                this.notifier.notify('error', 'Format code a bare invalide');
            } else if (this.idbordereaux.length != 10) {
                this.notifier.notify('error', 'Format code a bare invalide');
            } else if (this.idBourdereauIsValid == false) {
                this.notifier.notify('error', 'Bordereau n\'existe pas ');
            } else {
                if (this.map.size == 0) {
                    this.map.set(1, this.idbordereaux);
                } else {
                    let x: number = this.verifexistbordereau(this.idbordereaux);
                    if (x === 0) {
                        this.map.set(this.map.size + 1, this.idbordereaux);
                    } else {
                        this.notifier.notify('error', 'Bordereau N°' + this.idbordereaux + 'existe deja dans la liste!');
                    }
                }
            }
            this.idbordereaux = "";
        })
}
```